# Google UTM Campaign Tracking in AMP amp-analytics

Tags: google-analytics, amp-analytics

I am building an AMP website, and I use google analytics for tracking. However I found the `utm_campaign`, `utm_source` and `utm_medium` properties are not working when I migrate my site to AMP, it was working when I was using analytics.js. I tried to add `?utm_source=some_value&utm_campaign=some_value&utm_medium=some_value` at the end of url, it doesn't work. I tried to add these values through `extraUrlParams` in the `amp-analytics` configuration like this: `"extraUrlParams": {"utm_source": "test", "utm_campaign": "test", "utm_medium": "test"}`, it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

After some further digging, this problem solved. Here is how to solve the issue.

When a request comes in with `?utm_campaign=some_value&utm_medium=some_value&utm_source=some_value`, it probably not the actual link `amp-analytics` send to GA. Actually it is sending the `page_location` in the `amp-analytics` configuration.

So if your configuration is like this: `{"vars": {"gtag_id":"UA-XXXX-0", "config": {"UA-XXXX-0": {"page_title":"some_value","page_location":"$urlWithParams"}}}}`,  e.g. current page location is https://example.com/ , then the `page_location` should be like https://example.com/?utm_campaign=some_value&utm_source=some_value&utm_medium=some_value , then it will capture the UTM values. To achieve this, you can either get the current window location or url params using AMP url variables.